# MongoDb Java using sum() in Aggregations with literal value (not with reference)

Tags: mongodb-java

This Java statement

```
Aggregation.group("name").sum("1").as("count")
```

generates

```
{"$group" : { "_id": "$name", "count": { "$sum": "$1" } } }
```

I'd like to specify the $sum value without a reference (removing the **$**), so it becomes

```
{ "$sum": "1" }
```

How to do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With my original question, the aim was to use the aggregations via `MongoTemplate` from Spring, but I found a way to use it with `MongoClient` manually specifying the fields like this :

```
Bson group = new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$name").append("count", new Document("$sum", 1)));
Bson match = new Document("$match", new Document("count", new Document("$gt", 1)));

AggregateIterable<Document> documents = collection.aggregate(List.of(group, match));
```